# I do not get notified if a moderator edits my post

Tags: bug, edits, notifications

The title almost says it all:

I usually get a notification when somebody edits my questions or answers (which is good). However, today I noticed [an edit on one of my questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/125931/2) of which I wasn’t notified and the only reason I can think of is that the editor happened to be a moderator.

Comment: This got nothing to do with the editor being moderator, the edit is considered trivial thus not triggering a notification.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That could make a good answer

Comment: Hmm, I can't imagine how an edit that adds, removes, or changes a link in the post could ever be classified as trivial. That just seems wrong.