# Edit notifications sometimes not being delivered (ND)

Tags: support, edits, notifications, notification-bar

I have noticed my top-bar edit notifications (that is, being notified when other people edit my posts) to be somewhat erratic for a while.  Sometimes they're delivered and sometimes they aren't.  I haven't found a pattern to it (if indeed there is a pattern).  Some data points:

- [This post (on a per-site meta) was edited twice on the same day; I was notified of one of them](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/881/revisions)
- [I was not notified of this edit in the top bar nor in my network profile, but was on the site profile ("responses" tab)](https://pets.stackexchange.com/revisions/35/3)
- [I was not notified of this tag-only edit in the top bar or network profile, but was on the site profile](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/revisions/45147/2) (I'm not sure if tag-only edits are supposed to notify)

All of these edits occurred within the last week.  As I said, I've noticed, but didn't record, erratic behavior over the past few months.  In one past case I was away from the site long enough that it should have triggered an email notification and that didn't happen either.

Are there circumstances under which I'm not supposed to get edit notifications?  If so, what are they?

Comment: Minor edits do not cause notification. Please give some examples and we'll see. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I gave three examples in my question.  I'll keep my eye out for more.  (Pretty much by definition, I won't notice them right away.)  Is there a definition of "minor"?

Comment: Well, the second and third were too minor, less than 6 characters or tag only edits. As for title edit I'm almost sure it never considered minor so you might have experienced the same bug as reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236381/i-do-not-get-notified-if-a-moderator-edits-my-post).

Comment: I don't get edit notifications.

Comment: I'm intermittently not getting them either. I think it's safe to call this a [tag:bug].

Comment: [There are notifications only for “substantive edits”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202359/no-notification-was-received-for-an-edit-to-a-post). What's a substantive edit? “There are a few rules”, which I'm not sufficiently motivated to reverse engineer. This may be what you observed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202359/no-notification-was-received-for-an-edit-to-a-post), and this matches with what I've observed since asking this question, edits do not produce notifications if:

- only tags were edited
- the size of the edit, in characters, is small ("small" is not universally defined)

These are considered minor edits.  Titles have no special status when assessing whether something is "minor".

Comment: As far as I know, minor edit is considered less than 6 characters, where editing code, even one character, is always considered non minor.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think I've seen bigger edits, where only the title was changed, not generate notifications.  I don't know if this means title-only edits never notify or they do but only if some larger value.