# No notification when somebody edits the title of your question

Tags: bug, edits, global-inbox, title

I didn't get an inbox notification for [this edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/350981/revisions), even though [title edits are substantive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202415/295232) and you should get an [inbox notification for substantive edits by other users to your posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319354/295232).

I've retested this with a sandbox post on Ask Different Meta, same behaviour. I still get notifications for substantive body edits.

Comment: [Same happened to me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/399427/2) two days ago on meta SO. The editor was a moderator though. I'm not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: It looks like a **9** character difference, and there is [speculation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271146/282094) (in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239145/edit-notifications-sometimes-not-being-delivered-nd/271146#comment930868_271146)) that "substantive" for a title is more than six characters.