# Allow tag changes to notify when following a post

Tags: feature-request, tags, edits, notifications, follow-post

When a post is followed, and an edit only changes a tag, say [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) → [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), no notification is sent to the post follower. This may have to do with the [threshold for edits notification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271146/392799):

> - only tags were edited
> - the size of the edit, in characters, is small ("small" is not universally defined)

Still, that simple tag change, which is a reason for following, makes following in this case pointless. Can the threshold for following be altered to allow tag edits?

---

Related:

- [Why don't we receive notifications about the addition of moderator-only tags to meta requests? Should we?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319356/392799)

  - This is about normal notifications to post owner (who can still see the change under the *Responses* tab), not the follow-post feature

Comment: FWIW, I think they deliberately keep the triggers for notifications to the author and notification to the followers the same. If [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202359/295232) is still [tag:status-bydesign], I expect this request to be [tag:status-declined].

Comment: Well... I think the crux of what you want here is to be notified upon *moderator-only* tag changes, which is a much fairer ask than being notified of any tag-only or trivial edit. Am I right?

Comment: For strictly only mod tag edits, this is the dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319367/282094 - but this request implies ***all*** tag edits; even two with identical length, involving a "zero character" *change*.

Comment: I like this FR for moderator-only `status` retags. The other [linked FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371014) in the comments for lowering thresholds on posts not by the OP I would not be interested to see implemented.