# Please notify authors (and followers) of more edits

Tags: feature-request, edits, notifications

Currently, when an edit is made to a post, the author (and followers) of the post get notified only if it's considered "substantive", which is determined based on the criteria mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202415/348196). I'm paraphrasing here:

> - If an edit to a question title is over a threshold (10 characters on most sites). Or...
> - an edit in the post body is over a threshold (10 characters on most sites). Or...
> - an edit in code sections is over another threshold (2 characters on most sites, no threshold on sites with syntax highlighting disabled).
> - Retagging only is not considered "substantive" and does *not* send a notification.

In my opinion, that is not enough. There are certain situations where I (and I would imagine many users) would definitely want to be notified about the edit. So, I have two proposals. If both get implemented, that would be great; but if either one gets implemented, that would be fine too.

1. #### Add a "Receive notifications for all edits" option in settings

   This should be a per-site option and it would allow users to opt-in for receiving notifications about all edits made to their posts or posts they follow.
2. #### Tweak the criteria for what's considered a "substantive" edit

   It should include the following:

   - Any changes (addition/removal) to moderator tags (AKA, red tags) in the post.

     - This should also include tags in the body (at least in answers). So, adding/removing/editing things like `[tag:status-foo]` (or `[meta-tag:status-foo]` on child meta's) should trigger a notification.
   - TBD...

Comment: Related: [Allow tag changes to notify when following a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371011/348196)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notification when a trivial edit is made on my post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354592/282094)